# How modify comments metabox on post edit screen in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wp-admin, metabox, comments, screen-options

I search a solution for custom the comment's html on post edit screen when i click to the button "add new comment".

I want to add a ACF field in the form.

The codex not explain a solution...

Or an idee ?

Comment: I think that your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I just thought of a solution: Maybe create à new metabox via add_meta_box and call a normal form comments when in FrontOffice ?